# Control diff() in a data frame or tibble after pull() in a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame as bellow:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(Hospital = c("A", "B"), 
                     `mean(fortid)` = c(15.0627461443777, 14.9054535011833)), 
                row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) 

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Hospital `mean(fortid)`
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 A                  15.1
2 B                  14.9
```

I want to be able to control the diff, that is either `A - B (meaning 15.1 - 14.9` or `B- A (14.9 - 15.1)`. I can do

```
df %>% 
  pull() %>% 
  diff()
```

But then i cannot control how they are subtracted. Something like this would be great:

```
c("A", "B") which would be defined as A - B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do an `arrange` either ascendding or descending and can control the `diff`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(Hospital) %>% 
   pull(`mean(fortid)`) %>% 
    diff
```

---

If we need fine control

```
df %>%
   summarise(out = `mean(fortid)`[Hospital == 'A'] - `mean(fortid)`[Hospital == 'B'])
```

---

Or another option is `match` to get the index by passing the vector in the order we want

```
df %>%
    summarise(out = diff(`mean(fortid)`[match(c('A', 'B'), Hospital)]))
```

Comment: @ Hi akrun. I have to use it in a function so I would like a solution like ``c("A", "B")``